# Perl script to handle include files

Tags: perl

I am trying to extend the JSON format (for private use) to include an `include` statement. This could be used to include other `.json` files into a master file, for example.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Slurp 'read_file';

my $str=parseFile('t.json');

sub parseFile {
  my ($fn)=@_;

  my $str=read_file($fn);
  my $res='';
  my $i=0;
  while (1) {
    if ($str=~/include\s+"(.*?)"/) {
      $res=$res.$`.parseFile("include/$1.json");
      $str=$';
    } else {
      $res=$res.$str;
      last;
    }
  }
  return $res;
}
```

It seems to be working for some simple test cases. But is it too complicated or is it too simple?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `` $` `` and `$'` are very cryptic, I had to look them up in `man perlvar` to find that they contain whatever was before and after the match. It also turns out that they are *discouraged* due to performance considerations. Either way the `while` block really *smells*.

A simpler approach is to use `s///ge` to replace the matched pattern with the output of a function call, like this:

```
sub parseFile {
  my ($fn) = @_;
  my $str = read_file($fn);
  $str =~ s/include\s+"(.*?)"/parseFile("include\/$1.json")/ge;
  return $str;
}
```

Also consider adding some error handling. For example, what should happen if the file doesn't exist? Ignore / warn / raise error?

It might be a good idea to make `parseFile` handle multiple parameters:

```
sub parseFile {
    foreach my $fn (@_) {
        my $str = read_file($fn);
        $str =~ s/include\s+"(.*?)"/parseFile("include\/$1.json")/ge;
        return $str;
    }
}
```

Maybe you don't really need to handle multiple files, but a side effect of this approach is that it automatically handles the case gracefully if somebody incorrectly calls the method without any parameters.

Finally, notice that I used spaces around operators like `=` and `=~` to improve readability. I borrow this practice from other programming languages where this is a standard, and let's face it, Perl scripts need all the readability aid they can get...

#### UPDATE

[@amon](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/21609/amon) added some excellent points in his comment:

- Notice that in the replacement pattern `s/include\s+"(.*?)"/parseFile(".\/$1")/ge;` I had to escape the delimiter `/`. Another way is changing the delimiter so I don't have to escape anything: `s{include\s+"(.*?)"}{parseFile("include/$1")}ge;`
- My multi-argument suggestion is kinda broken, because of the return statement: it will only process the first file. It would be better to use `Carp::confess "parseFile expects one file name or file handle" if not @_ == 1`, and the caller could still `map { parseFile($_) } @files` if really required

Comment: Thanks @janos for the comments! I forgot about the `e` modifier; seems like you can make good use of it here :) Now the code looks quite elegant.

Comment: A review-review: ① If you have to escape a delimiter in Perl, switch the delimiter. E.g. you could use `s{}{}` to avoid escaping that forward slash. ② Your multi-argument variant doesn't work, because it will `return` the first result. In programming, there is little space for “degrading gracefully”. I recommend `Carp::confess "parseFile expects one file name or file handle" if not @_ == 1` instead – a caller could still `map { parseFile($_) } @files` if really required. ③ Otherwise, good points → +1